# Airflow 2 import exception

Tags: installation, airflow

I uninstalled airflow 1.10.12 and installed airflow 2 using python 3.6.9. When I start the webserver without custom DAGs I get warnings:

```
[2021-01-12 11:38:58,095] {dagbag.py:440} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /dev/null
[2021-01-12 11:38:59,049] {providers_manager.py:283} WARNING - Exception when importing 'airflow.providers.google.cloud.hooks.dataprep.GoogleDataprepHook' from 'apache-airflow-providers-google' package: No module named 'airflow.providers.google.cloud'
[2021-01-12 11:38:59,050] {providers_manager.py:283} WARNING - Exception when importing 'airflow.providers.google.cloud.hooks.cloud_sql.CloudSQLHook' from 'apache-airflow-providers-google' package: No module named 'airflow.providers.google.cloud'
[2021-01-12 11:38:59,050] {providers_manager.py:283} WARNING - Exception when importing 'airflow.providers.google.cloud.hooks.cloud_sql.CloudSQLDatabaseHook' from 'apache-airflow-providers-google' package: No module named 'airflow.providers.google.cloud'
[2021-01-12 11:38:59,050] {providers_manager.py:283} WARNING - Exception when importing 'airflow.providers.google.cloud.hooks.compute_ssh.ComputeEngineSSHHook' from 'apache-airflow-providers-google' package: No module named 'airflow.providers.google.cloud'
[2021-01-12 11:38:59,050] {providers_manager.py:283} WARNING - Exception when importing 'airflow.providers.google.cloud.hooks.bigquery.BigQueryHook' from 'apache-airflow-providers-google' package: No module named 'airflow.providers.google.cloud'
[2021-01-12 11:38:59,051] {providers_manager.py:283} WARNING - Exception when importing 'airflow.providers.google.common.hooks.base_google.GoogleBaseHook' from 'apache-airflow-providers-google' package: No module named 'airflow.providers.google.common'
[2021-01-12 11:38:59,117] {providers_manager.py:283} WARNING - Exception when importing 'airflow.providers.google.cloud.hooks.dataprep.GoogleDataprepHook' from 'apache-airflow-providers-google' package: No module named 'airflow.providers.google.cloud'
[2021-01-12 11:38:59,117] {providers_manager.py:283} WARNING - Exception when importing 'airflow.providers.google.cloud.hooks.cloud_sql.CloudSQLHook' from 'apache-airflow-providers-google' package: No module named 'airflow.providers.google.cloud'
[2021-01-12 11:38:59,118] {providers_manager.py:283} WARNING - Exception when importing 'airflow.providers.google.cloud.hooks.cloud_sql.CloudSQLDatabaseHook' from 'apache-airflow-providers-google' package: No module named 'airflow.providers.google.cloud'
[2021-01-12 11:38:59,118] {providers_manager.py:283} WARNING - Exception when importing 'airflow.providers.google.cloud.hooks.compute_ssh.ComputeEngineSSHHook' from 'apache-airflow-providers-google' package: No module named 'airflow.providers.google.cloud'
[2021-01-12 11:38:59,118] {providers_manager.py:283} WARNING - Exception when importing 'airflow.providers.google.cloud.hooks.bigquery.BigQueryHook' from 'apache-airflow-providers-google' package: No module named 'airflow.providers.google.cloud'
[2021-01-12 11:38:59,118] {providers_manager.py:283} WARNING - Exception when importing 'airflow.providers.google.common.hooks.base_google.GoogleBaseHook' from 'apache-airflow-providers-google' package: No module named 'airflow.providers.google.common'
```

Can this be ignored or what could be the reason?

Regards
Oli

Answer (score 2):

These are warnings for missing modules.
Airflow changed structure while 1.0>2.0

You can either ignore these, if not planning to use google cloud plugins, or install additional modules:

```
pip install --upgrade apache-airflow-providers-google
```

After installing above you would probably need more modules like mysql, paramiko and ssh.
You can install them with:

```
pip install --upgrade paramiko
pip install --upgrade apache-airflow-providers-ssh
pip install --upgrade apache-airflow-providers-mysql
```